# C# display array length when a number is entered

Tags: c#

I want to input a number which corresponds to the length of an array and I want the number at that position to be displayed

```
Console.WriteLine("ENter the length");

int[] array1 = { 0, 6, 7, 8, 5 };

int lenght = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for (int i = 0; i <= lenght; i++)
{
    lenght = array1.Length;
    Console.WriteLine(lenght);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I expect the output of 2 to be 7 but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: `if (lenght < array1.Length) Console.WriteLine(array1[lenght]);`? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Arrays have "length" and "elements at indexes" - it is *very* unclear what you are looking for here as word "length" in the post seem to be used for something that is not conventional meaning for array.

Comment: `int[] array1 = { 0, 6, 7, 8, 5 };

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the index");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int index);
            if(index < array1.Length)            
                Console.WriteLine(array1[index]);
            
            Console.ReadLine();` I didn't feel the need to add an answer - break down: make sure user enters a valid number, if so and it's less than the array print the number at that index.

Comment: Or another option yet is a list and some `Linq`: `List<int> listNumbers = new List<int>() { 12, 3, 65, 23, 54 };
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the index");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int newIndex);
            Console.WriteLine(listNumbers.Select((number, numIndex) => new { number, numIndex }).Where(a => a.numIndex == newIndex)?.FirstOrDefault()?.number);`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample expected output, it appears that you're talking about retrieving an element at a given index rather than actual length.

So if you want to retrieve the element at index `2` (which, according to your sample, would be `7`) then:

```
Console.WriteLine(array1[length]);
```

Note that you don't have to iterate through the array if you only need to print just one value. Also inside the loop you do this, which will overwrite the user input you got making the input redundant.

```
lenght = array1.Length;
```

So if you want the element at a given index your program would be like this:

```
int[] array1 = { 0, 6, 7, 8, 5 };

Console.Write("Enter the Index: ");
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int index);

if (index < array1.Length)
    Console.WriteLine(array1[index]);
```

Also, instead of `int.Parse()` try using `int.TryParse()` as shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
array1[lenght]
```

This will return the number 7 when `lenght` is 2.  However, you should consider the case when the user enters a number that is not valid.  Also, `lenght` might be better named `index` because it's not representing the length of the array.  From what you've described, it sounds like you want the value at a particular index.

Comment: Although OP misspelled length/lenght in the question, I think it'd be better if you corrected it in your answer.

Comment: @Joelius even though the user has spelled a word wrong, that doesn't affect the outcome of this answer and nor the OP issue. Also I would assume you would have mentioned this on the other answer as well?

Comment: @Codexer of course it doesn't affect the outcome but this answer contains devlins code and if I was them, I wouldn't want spelling errors in my answers. It has no disadvantages and it's a thing that OP arguably did wrong, so you should probably correct it if you know the solution. And yes, I wanted to mention it on the other answer as well as provide edits for the question and the answers but I didn't have time :)

Comment: I have no knowledge of whether or not a variable name is spelled correctly.  It could be an intentional mis-spelling.  I followed the OP's spelling since it's a variable.